# How to send data to a date textbox with Selenium?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, selenium, element

This is the example of my coding that I want to send data to and it works. It's a dropdown element.

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[@id='select2-ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormEngine1_mf_18a384bd-8919-4aa7-b953-528b33a775dd_ddlGroup-results']/li[. ='" & roaData(3) & "']")).Click()
```

Here is the real problem I'm facing. Below here is the code that I want to send data to the element but it is not working. I want to send the data of the date but its not catching the data. The element is a calendar textbox.

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormEngine1_ctl61_txtDate']")).SendKeys(UCase(Format(roaData(2), "dd MMMM yyyy")))
```

Any solution guys? Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the HTML of the target element nor what `roaData(2)` contains it's not very easy to tell what the issue is, but like most input elements the contents of a textbox is usually located in the `value` attribute. So instead of `SendKeys()` I recommend you use `setAttribute()`:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormEngine1_ctl61_txtDate']")).setAttribute("value", roaData(2).ToString("dd MMMM yyyy").ToUpper())
```

Also note that `UCase` and `Format` are old functions from the VB6 era, existing only to provide backwards compatibility with that language. I replaced them with the .NET variants [`DateTime.ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_) (assuming `roaData(2)` is actually of type `Date`) and [`String.ToUpper()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.toupper?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_ToUpper).

Comment: If this solution does not work please post the HTML code of the element you are trying to change as well as the type _**and content**_ of `roaData(2)`.

Comment: HTML code of element
<td id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormEngine1_ctl61_DatePickers1"><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FormEngine1$ctl61$txtDate" type="text" value="1 APRIL 2019" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormEngine1_ctl61_txtDate" class="formdatetimepicker_normal" onfocus="this.className='formdatetimepicker_focus';" onblur="this.className='formdatetimepicker_normal';__doPostBack('ctl00_UpdatePanel1$DefaultButtonClick','Allotmentdate');return false;__doPostBack('ctl00_UpdatePanel1','');" data-datepicker-max-today="true" readonly="readonly" style="text-transform: uppercase;"></td>

Comment: The content of roaData(2) is the Date

Comment: @Keyah : I'm not much into Selenium, but from what I can tell it should work. What happens if you try finding it just by ID instead: `By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormEngine1_ctl61_txtDate")`? Based on the existing value of the element (`1 APRIL 2019`) you might also want to try the format `d MMMM yyyy` since it has no leading zeros.